# Labeling triangle edges in Mathematica 10

Tags: graphics, regions, version-10

Mathematica 10 introduced lots of new geometry related functions, and one of these is [SSSTriangle](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SSSTriangle.html) which creates a triangle graphic given the three side lengths. Is it possible however to label the side lengths to achieve something like this

[image]

Comment: If we can figure out how to convert this to a `MeshRegion`, then this is possible with `HighlightMesh`.

Comment: I thought you said you wanted the `to label the side lengths` so the labels should be the actual lengths? That is what I understood it as, It seems you just wanted any labels, but your example shows the lengths on the edges.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use:

```
HighlightMesh[DiscretizeGraphics[SSSTriangle[3, 4, 5]], 
 Labeled[1, "Index"]]
```

[image]

Or,

```
HighlightMesh[
 DiscretizeGraphics[SSSTriangle[3, 4, 5]], {Labeled[{1, 1}, 5], 
  Labeled[{1, 2}, 3], Labeled[{1, 3}, 4]}]
```

to get:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
 coords=Sequence@@(SSSTriangle[3,4,5]);
 i=1;
 Graphics[{Yellow, EdgeForm[Black], SSSTriangle[3,4,5], Black,
     (Inset[Panel[Style[i++,16]],#]&/@Mean/@Transpose[{coords,RotateRight@coords}])}]
```

[image]

or

```
CycleGraph[3, VertexCoordinates -> SSSTriangle[3,4,5][[1]],
   EdgeLabels->{1<->2 ->Panel[1],1<->3 ->Panel[2],2<->3 ->Panel[3]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you join me in chat?

Comment: Hi @Szabolcs, just saw your chat invite..

Answer (score 5):

Kguler solution is much nicer, but here is my attempt. I solve the equation of lines to find the coordinate needed, then superimpose `SSSTriangle` with `Graph` using `EdgeLabels` where the length is put as the Label. Can be made shorter and more functional. The manual part of mapping edges to labels below can be automated more if needed.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
len = {3, 4, 5};
g = SSSTriangle[3, 4, 5];
{x0, y0} = N@RegionCentroid[g]
{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}} = N@RegionBounds[g]
xTop = x /. First@Solve[(x0 - (x2 - x1)/2)/(y0 - y1) == (x - x0)/(y2 - y0), x];
points = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y1}, {xTop, y2}}
g1 = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, VertexCoordinates -> points, 
   EdgeLabels -> {1 <-> 2 -> len[[3]], 2 <-> 3 -> len[[1]], 3 <-> 1 -> len[[2]]},
   EdgeLabelStyle -> Large];
Show[Graphics[{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black], g, AspectRatio -> 1}], g1]
```

And if you want the centroid lines, they come for free after all the above work:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
en = {3, 4, 5};
g = SSSTriangle[3, 4, 5];
{x0, y0} = N@RegionCentroid[g]
{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}} = N@RegionBounds[g]
xTop = x /. First@Solve[(x0 - (x2 - x1)/2)/(y0 - y1) == (x - x0)/(y2 - y0), x];
points = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y1}, {xTop, y2}}
g1 = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, VertexCoordinates -> points, 
   EdgeLabels -> {1 <-> 2 -> len[[3]], 2 <-> 3 -> len[[1]], 3 <-> 1 -> len[[2]]},
   EdgeLabelStyle -> Large];
Show[Graphics[{
   {FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black], g}, Line[{{x1, y1}, {x0, y0}}],
   Line[{{x0, y0}, {x2, y1}}],
   Line[{{x0, y0}, {xTop, y2}}]}],
 g1]
```

Another option instead of using Graph is to use `BoundaryMeshRegion` to add the labels
(there might be a way to use `MesgRegion` directly on `SSSTriangle` but can't get it to work)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
len = {3, 4, 5};
g = SSSTriangle[3, 4, 5];
{x0, y0} = N@RegionCentroid[g]
{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}} = N@RegionBounds[g]
xTop = x /. First@Solve[(x0 - (x2 - x1)/2)/(y0 - y1) == (x - x0)/(y2 - y0), x];
points = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y1}, {xTop, y2}}
g1 = BoundaryMeshRegion[points, Line[{1, 2, 3, 1}], 
   MeshCellLabel -> {{{1, 1}} -> len[[3]], {{1, 2}} -> len[[1]],{{1, 3}}->len[[2]]}];
Show[Graphics[{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black], g}], g1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my late attempt based off my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112697/how-to-assign-element-marker-at-boundary-edges/112719#112719).

```
tri = DiscretizeGraphics @ SSSTriangle[3, 4, 5];
```

Using `PropertyValue` we can set the labels to be part of the triangle:

```
PropertyValue[{tri, {1, All}}, MeshCellLabel] = 
              Style[Framed[#], Bold, Red, 10, Background -> Yellow] & /@ {5, 3, 4};
```

Visualize:

```
tri
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1).Very nice answer.Just confusing how do you know the property of `MeshCellLabel`.When I use `PropertyList` try to get it,I get a `$Failed` or a blank output [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WsKBT.png).

Answer (score 0):

**Using `RegionMeasure`, `MeshPrimitives`:** (introduced 9th July 2014)

```
tri = SSSTriangle[3, 4, 5];
Graphics[{
  {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], tri}
  , Text[Framed[
      Style[NumberForm[RegionMeasure@#, {3, 2}], 14, Red]
      , Background -> Lighter@Yellow
      ], Midpoint@#
     ] & /@ MeshPrimitives[tri, 1]
  }
 ]
```

[image]