# How to assign Element marker at boundary edges

Tags: computational-geometry, regions, mesh, finite-element-method

How to assign marker at the boundary edges as 1, 2, 3, 4 respectively and set all of the inside elements of region as 0? for example:

[image]

Code:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5]];
ToElementMesh[bmesh]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: @RunnyKine, I think I can get what I want from your answer, let me work on it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this question has a FEM tag, I assume that the mesh is for applying boundary conditions to a PDE. If that is the case, then the solution suggested by @RunnyKine can be improved.

What you are looking for are the `"PointMarkerFunction"` and the `"BoundaryMarkerFunction"`. Now, it is important to understand that markers can be applied to points for `DirichletConditions` via `PointElements`, to edges/surfaces for NeumannValues via `BoundaryElements` and to region components via `MeshElements` for PDE coefficients. Once markers are in a mesh these are independent from each other. That means a `NeumannValue` that looks for a `ElementMaker` does not care about markers in point or mesh elements only about markers in boundary elements. So if you ask for markers in edges that will ever only be useful for `NeumannValues`.

To get your requested marker in the mesh you can use a small function

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
boundaryMarkerFunction = 
  Compile[{{boundaryElementCoords, _Real, 
     3}, {pointMarkres, _Integer, 2}},
   Range[Length[boundaryElementCoords]]];
```

This is going to return a marker for every boundary element. To create the mesh use:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5], 
   "BoundaryMarkerFunction" -> 
    boundaryMarkerFunction    
(*Optional for better visualization of this example *)   
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1,
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.2,
   PrecisionGoal -> 10^-3
   ];
```

This then gives

```
Show[mesh[
  "Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
   "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Red]]
 , mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "MeshElements", 
   "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue]]
 ]
```

[image]

There are a few things to note: First, the default mesh element marker is 0, so there was no need to set anything. If you want a different marker then 0, you can use `"RegionMarker"\[Rule]{{{0,0},1}}` to specify a 1 marker.

Next, if you look at the `PointElement` markers you'll see:

```
Show[mesh[
  "Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
   "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Magenta]]
 , mesh["Wireframe"]
 ]
```

[image]

So, the makers there have been derived from the edge markers specified. You can overwrite that by specifying a `PointMarkerFunction`. There are a few examples in the FEM documentation of [ToElementMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html) in the options sections and in the [ElementMesh generation tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html).

Why should you use `ToElementMesh` for that? To main reasons: First the FEM code will not understand the labels specified for the mesh region (that could be made to work) but secondly, the mesh is much more accurate:

```
(* MeshRegion *)
\[Pi] (1/2)^2 - 0.782472
0.0029261633974483336`

(* ElementMesh *)
\[Pi] (1/2)^2 - Total[Join @@ mesh["MeshElementMeasure"]]
0.0000174314511414142`
```

So, even for such a coarse FEM `ElementMesh`, the accuracy of the area is much better because it's a second order mesh and the `MeshRegion` is first order only. If you do FEM then I'd recommend to use `ToElementMesh`

Comment: Do you think some of these FEM functionalities will be built-in in future versions?

Comment: @RunnyKine, I guess if there are enough requests for that (you may want to send that request to the support) it may happen.

Comment: Ok. Will send a request. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an approach using built-in functions:

```
reg = DiscretizeRegion[Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5], MeshCellHighlight -> {{2, All} -> White}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, we obtain the outer points:

```
int = MeshCellIndex[reg, {0, "Interior"}][[All,2]] (* interior points *)
ext = Complement[MeshCellIndex[reg, 0][[All,2]], int] (* exterior points *)
```

Finally, we set the properties of the region (interior and exterior points) using `PropertyValue` and `MeshCellLabel`:

```
PropertyValue[{reg, {0, ext}}, MeshCellLabel] = 
  Style[#, Bold, Darker @ Red, 8] & /@ Range @ Length @ ext;

PropertyValue[{reg, {0, int}}, MeshCellLabel] = 
  Style[#, Bold, Darker @ Blue, 8] & /@ Table[0, Length @ int];
```

Let's visualize:

```
reg
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that this is still very much a region and you can compute various properties as usual:

```
Area @ reg
```

> 0.782472

Comment: I added an answer that refers to yours and I wanted to notify you about that.