# Confused about the behavior of the properties of Regions

Tags: computational-geometry, regions

Actually we can get some information in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=EdgeLengths).But I'm confuse this phenomenon still:

```
test = ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[1, {7, 2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
test["EdgeLengths"]
```

> {0.192337,0.4887,0.176702,0.185319,0.564806,0.428493,0.805059}

But the same result will not appear this case,

```
region = BoundaryMesh[DiscretizeRegion[SSSTriangle[3, 4, 5]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
region /@ {"AdjacencyMatrix", "EdgeLengths"}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I think if the properties of `"EdgeLengths"` can work normally,it will help a lot to [Labeling triangle edges in Mathematica 10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54697/labeling-triangle-edges-in-mathematica-10).

**Note this,please.** these region have a same head.

```
Head /@ {test, region}
```

> {BoundaryMeshRegion, BoundaryMeshRegion}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are using is an undocumented feature in these region objects, so I wouldn't expect it to work properly.

You can see some of the properties by using:

```
region["Properties"]
```

The list is quite long so I won't be including it here. Now, both of your regions will show `"EdgeLengths"` as one of the properties, so you clearly see that this undocumented feature is not completely fleshed-out. 
What's documented though, is the `PropertyValue` approach (well, partly at least), so let's use it:

```
PropertyValue[{test, 1}, MeshCellMeasure]
(* {0.261146, 0.694517, 0.406227, 0.339956, 0.576842} *)

PropertyValue[{region, 1}, MeshCellMeasure] (* This gives the length of the sides *)
(* {5., 3., 4.} *)
```

The `1` means we want the 1-D measure, which is the length of the edges. If you want the area, use `2`, etc. One should be able to use `PropertyList` to obtain possible properties of a region, but this doesn't always work. Even in the "possible issues" section of the documentation for `PropertyValue` (which only shows example of its use with `Graph`s), it says:

> PropertyValue may return $Failed even when a property value exists:

Then shows an example where this happens. Clearly, even this approach is a work in progress.

**Update**

On the other hand if you still want to access the undocumented `"Properties"` of the regions, you can still use the also undocumented approach by calling `` Graphics`Region`ToMeshObject `` on the mesh objects e,g.

```
treg = Graphics`Region`ToMeshObject[region];
```

Then you can now call `"EdgeLengths"` and other properties:

```
treg /@ {"AdjacencyMatrix", "EdgeLengths"}

(* {{{0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}}, {5., 3., 4.}} *)
```

Comment: Grateful for your patient explanation.:)

Comment: @yode. You're welcome. We're all confused about some of the region functions.

Comment: I just guess such as ``Graphics`Region`ToMeshObject`` maybe give a help,but I don't sure. I remain it open for some time.